# HoloEverywhere dropdown items too big

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, spinner

I'm using HoloEverywhere for my Android application and the dropdown items are rather odd. They are way bigger than they are in native Android 4+ and bigger than necessary. This for example is how it looks for a [Dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE2rd.jpg) and this is when used in a [spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM8in.jpg).

I've searched the styles of HoloEverywhere and found some resources I think could be responsible for this oversize. Of course I can't just change those attributes in the library, I need to somehow override them for my application.

But what is the easiest way to change the height of the dropdown items?

EDIT:

This was actually a bug in the older version of HoloEverywhere I was using. It's been fixed now and all the dropdown-items look the way they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as follows...

1>create menu in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/spinner_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="always" 
    android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner" />
</menu>
```

2>set your layout as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinner_menu"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
/>
```

3>then in the onCreateOptionsMenu call necessary methods and set values accordingly...

for more information refer the link below...

[how to create custom drop down menu with actionbarsherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106399/how-to-create-custom-drop-down-menu-with-actionbarsherlock)

Comment: OK no, now the menu doesn't work at all. But I'll continue trying.